# Looking for quote about workhouses

Tags: political-history, social-history, united-kingdom

I recall someone (may MP at the time) said something like.

> No one that is in real need should be discouraged from using a
>   workhouse due to its standard of housing and food, but on one that is
>   not in real need should wish to use one due to its standard of housing
>   and food.

Can anyone recall who said it and the correct wording.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar recollection. You might consult the British History Magazine podcast on workhouses (within the last 6 months, although I have trouble searching their archives); that is where I'm most likely to have heard it.

Third google result is "Recollections of Workhouse Visiting and Management During Twenty-five Years" [link](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=3T8XAAAAYAAJ&rdid=book-3T8XAAAAYAAJ&rdot=1) Page 68 of this book contains a quote similar to what you suggest, (*I haven't mastered the art of quoting from google books*) The same quote is in [Women's Work](https://books.google.com/books?id=OhRcAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA22&ots=G9BgBO6QOS&dq=No%20one%20that%20is%20in%20real%20need%20should%20be%20discouraged%20from%20using%20a%20workhouse&pg=PA22#v=onepage&q=No%20one%20that%20is%20in%20real%20need%20should%20be%20discouraged%20from%20using%20a%20workhouse&f=false), where in a footnote it is attributed to Sir F.B. Head.

There is some vaguely similar language in the [1832 Commission report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_to_the_English_Poor_Laws#The_1832_Royal_Commission); not close enough to be useful, but I suspect that the debate, and possibly the writings of Chadwick or Bentham might be a useful line of research.

Comment: It's amazing how little things change. "Every penny bestowed, that tends to render the condition of the pauper more eligible than that of the independent labourer, is a bounty on indolence and vice." - 1832 Royal Commission. Almost exactly the same arguments now.

Comment: @James the rules of logic haven't changed in the meantime.

Comment: @hobbs Yes, but ideologies and base assumptions do.